# Troubleshooting Infopath 2010 data connection (<conn name>) has exceeded the maximum configured time limit

Tags: infopath, error, time-out

We are using SP2010 with InfoPath 2010. One of our InfoPath form (browser based) will add records into a SharePoint list thru a DataConnection called "Details_Update" when user press "Submit" button.

It works fine for last 2 years but recently our users sometimes get an error. After checking the log we found:

> The following data connection (Details_Update) has exceeded the
>   maximum configured time limit. This threshold can be configured by
>   using the SPIPFormsService -MaxDataConnectionRoundTrip PowerShell
>   commandlet

The form will only add 1-10 records to a SharePoint list. Also the site is not busy. In average only several users use the form. The list contains about 50,000 records.

Although the error suggest to increase MaxDataConnectionRoundTrop (right now is 20000), I am not sure how much I should add and should I do it?

How can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the Info Path form services data connection round trip data connection time out value is exceeded. Round trip data connection time out value cannot be set through UI in the Central administration site, it has to be done using Power Shell scripts.

**To increase time out value :**

```
Set-SPInfoPathFormsService -MaxDataConnectionRoundTrip 25000
```

Reference Link [Issue with InfoPath data connection MaxDataConnectionRoundTrip time out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_infopath_bloggers/2015/05/28/issue-with-infopath-data-connection-maxdataconnectionroundtrip-time-out/)

Get value of all InfoPath form services settings :

```
$SPInfopath=Get-SPInfoPathFormsService

$SPInfopath| select *
```

Comment: Should I adjust upward the value until no more error occur?

Comment: Yes you can adjust. Increasing time out value is always based on the business requirements and to be done with lot of caution. It might cause performance issues. To be tested in a test farm before applying on the production.